# Making du'a and touching prayer map

Tags: halal-haram, salat, dua, menses

Asalam alaykum. I have 2 questions:

1) Can women touch the prayer map when they are in menses?

2) When women make du'as, are their duas going to be accepted? How can they proceed for their du'as to be accepted while they are in such a state?

Comment: Would you please illustrate what prayer map is?

Comment: Prayer map is the map U put down when praying,what U pray on...

Comment: The map is only a tool to help you praying on a pure ground.

Answer (score 1):

```
In regard to your initial question that you inquired:
```

> Can women touch the prayer map when they are in menses?

The response is that there is no problem if you touch that.

In regard to your second inquiry that you inquired:

> When women make du'as, are their duas going to be accepted? How can
>   they proceed for their du'as to be accepted while they are in such a
>   state?

As far as I search regarding making Dua for women while they are in menstruation, it doesn’t seem to be any specific problem in that, besides, Allah is so Rahman/الرحمن (merciful) to give your wishes. Then you’d better trust Allah and continue doing that.

---

**Reference :**

- [http://www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa11924)